# How to get all unique objects (with two values) in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm storing some coordinates in an array. It looks like this:

```
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}]
```

How can I filter this array so the objects are unique, meaning there are no duplicates of objects with same x and y value? Expected output should be:

```
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}]
```

I've seen some similar solutions, but they didn't really solve this problem.
I started with the following function

```
const output = Object.values(
  coords.reduce( (c, e) => {
    if (!c[e.x]) c[e.x] = e;
    return c;
  }, {})
```

but it only returns objects with different x values, so it just completely ommits y value.

Comment: Do you understand how this `reduce` call works, though? Your hash key is `e.x`, so of course it only deduplicates based on `x`. You hash key does not include `y`, so why not simply include `y`? For example, make the key `\`${e.x}-${e.y}\``. By the way, in the future, [Records](//github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) can be used for this: `new Set([ #{ x: 260, y: 60 }, #{ x: 180, y: 0 },`…`])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce),
along with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get the required result.

We'd add each item to the map, using the concatenated x and y values as keys, then return the values() to get de-duplicated values.

This will have complexity of O(n), so it will be efficient for large arrays.

```js
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}];

const dedup = [...coords.reduce((map, { x, y }) => {
   return (map.set(`${x}-${y}`, { x, y }));
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log('De-duplicated:', dedup)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or with a regular object:

```js
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}];

const dedup = Object.values(coords.reduce((acc, { x, y }) => { 
    return { ...acc, [`${x}-${y}`]: { x, y }}
}, {}));

console.log('De-duplicated:', dedup)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to use a Set, map the x & y into a string, and then deserialize the Set to have unique x,y's..

eg..

```js
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}];

const dedup = [...new Set(coords.map(m => `${m.x}:${m.y}`))].map(m => {
  const [x,y] = m.split(':').map(n => n | 0);
  return {x,y};
});

console.log(dedup);
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty inefficient (O(n^2)), but flexible and straightforward solution: You first define a function that checks if two coordinates are equal. Then you filter all elements which have an equal element at a later position in the array.

```js
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}]

const customUnique = (arr, isEqual) => {
  // filter elements where an equal element exists at an earlier position
  // thus the first element is kept
  return arr.filter((a, i) => !arr.some((b, j) => i > j && isEqual(a, b)))
}

console.log(customUnique(coords, (a, b) => a.x === b.x && a.y === b.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `originalArray.reduce()` with an array instead of an object, so you can make use of array.find.

```js
const coords = [{x: 260, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 0}, {x: 180, y: 240}, {x: 360, y: 120}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}, {x: 180, y: 60}]

console.log(
  coords.reduce((arr, e) => {
    if (!arr.find(item => item.x == e.x && item.y == e.y)) {
      arr.push(e);
    }
    return arr;
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: That's very interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

Yet another simple solution using a temporary array. However not the best as I could say:

```js
const filteredCoords: any = [];

for(let coord of coords)
  if (!filteredCoords.find((ele: { x: number; y: number; }) => ele.x == coord.x && ele.y == coord.y)){
    filteredCoords.push(coord)
}
```

Comment: But pretty simple to understand. Thanks man!